# Assigning column values to grouped astropy table within a loop

Tags: python, astropy, grouped-table

I have a grouped astropy table and would like to loop over the groups and perform a clipped mean on each group separately.

The MWE below illustrates what I am trying to do. When the code runs, it does not throw out an error, rather the values for the column 'c' just remain as 0.0. I feel like I am perhaps fundamentally misunderstanding something in how the table environment works, but am not sure exactly what.

```
import numpy as np
from astropy.table import Table
from astropy.stats import sigma_clip

a = np.array([5.7, 5.9, 5.1, 5.3, 5.7, 5.4, 6.0, 8.6, 6.4, 5.2])
b = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
c = np.zeros(len(a))

tab = Table( (a,b,c), names=('a','b','c'), masked=True )

tabGrp = tab.group_by('b')

for x in tabGrp.groups:
    clipped = sigma_clip( x['a'], sigma=2)
    x['c'] = clipped
```

Answer (score 0):

When you group your `tab` table, a new `groups` property [is added](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/table/operations.html#table-groups).

You can apply `sigma_clip()` on each `tabGrp` group, store *only the values* in a list, create a new [MaskedColumn](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/api/astropy.table.MaskedColumn.html) with this stored values (properly masking values), and replace the old `c` column with the new clipped one.

It is not very elegant, but is seems to do what you need.

```
import numpy as np
from astropy.table import Table
from astropy.stats import sigma_clip
from astropy.table import MaskedColumn

a = np.array([5.7, 4.2, 5.1, 5.3, 5.7, 5.4, 6.0, 8.6, 6.4, 5.2])
b = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
c = np.zeros(len(a))

tab = Table((a, b, c), names=('a', 'b', 'c'), masked=True)

tabGrp = tab.group_by('b')
clipped = sigma_clip(tabGrp['a'], sigma=2)

col = []
for x in tabGrp.groups:
    clipped = sigma_clip(x['a'], sigma=2)
    # Save values only.
    col += clipped.tolist()

# Create new masked column.
c_clipped = MaskedColumn(col, mask=[True if _ is None else False for _ in col])
# Replace old c column
tab['c'] = c_clipped
```

Which results in:

```
 a   b   c 
--- --- ---
5.7   0 5.7
4.2   0 4.2
5.1   0 5.1
5.3   0 5.3
5.7   1 5.7
5.4   1 5.4
6.0   1 6.0
8.6   1  --
6.4   1 6.4
5.2   1 5.2
```

Is this what you were after?

Comment: Not quite what I'm looking for - if we instead set a[2] = 4.2 it should illustrate better what I want.  Then, if we were to perform the sigma clip on the entire array a, then a[2] would be masked. But, if we performed the sigma clip on the two groups separately (which is what I want), then a[2] would not be masked.

Comment: Ok, so `4.2` should not be masked from group 1 and `8.6` should be masked from group 2? And this clipped groups should be combined into a single column and stored as `c` in your table (thus replacing your existing `c` column)?